# Extern Link open in a new Safari Window (PWA iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, hyperlink, safari, progressive-web-apps

The following problem:
I have a PWA for iOS and want to open a download link in an external link.This means that a completely external and new Safari window should open during the download.
I have the following code:

<a class="btn btn-primary" rel="noreferrer external" style=" width: 105px; margin-right: 10px; color:white" href="@URL" target="_blank" @onclick="close">Save

It does open a new browser page for me, but from there it jumps directly to the file manager, where I have no chance to return to the PWA. The only possibility is to close the PWA and start it again.

Does anyone have a solution that solves exactly this problem? Is there a way to open a new window, complete the download and then click on the Home button to bring the PWA forward again?